# Android Listview / item / textview / shape

Tags: android, listview

here you see the end of my items/groupitems of a listview/expandablelistview.

There are a textview with a Background shape.

[image]

I would like to make the textview clickable but ... it is too small ...

Now I would like to span the shape over the whole Background (height) top to bottom

but how to?

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ett"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/laptop"
    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
    android:paddingRight="5sp"
    android:paddingTop="1sp"
    android:paddingBottom="1sp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="Set"
    android:background="@drawable/mbutt_setup"
    android:focusable="false"
    />
```

Comment: why have you given padding in sp?

Comment: Padding should be in `dp`, not `sp`.

Answer (score 1):

1. To expand the clickable area of a textview, you can use a touch delegate. It is well explained in the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate
2. Your textview already expand to the whole height of its parent (`android:layout_height="match_parent"`) which mean either the background is not a 9patch (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) or the parent of the textview is smaller than the cell height.
3. The SP dimension should be used for text and not for layout sizes. Consider replacing `padding="5sp" with padding="5dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Now i have changed the Background from shape to normal Color tag #??????

[image]

it seems that textview is parent from groupitemindex or  rel. layout

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


        android:background="@drawable/elv_c_g_line">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/laptop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:textSize="23dp"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ett"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/laptop"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:paddingRight="5sp"
        android:paddingTop="1sp"
        android:paddingBottom="1sp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Set"
        android:background="#33ff33"
        android:focusable="false"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But rel layout is already match parent - so I have not the whole space to cover - the Background auf groupitem is a shape too - no 9pic